# How can I tell what is really draining my battery?

Tags: cyanogenmod, battery, battery-life

I know that by going to `Settings > About Phone > Battery Use`, I can get some idea of the applications that are using up the most of my battery. I see things like "Cell standby", "Phone idle", and "Wi-fi"; **is there any way to drill down even further and find out what is really draining my battery**? For example, I am fairly certain that GPS usage is included under 'Cell Standby'.

Any help would be appreciated; I have had my phone for only about three months, and the battery goes from 100% to 0% over the course of two-ish days with minimal usage (some browsing, check-ins), and I cannot figure what is draining the battery.

**EDIT**

I am mostly interested in ways of diagnosing power usage in a less broad way, but in the interests of finding out what could possibly be draining my battery, here is what my 'battery use' is reporting at the moment:

- 38% - Cell Standby
- 33% - Phone Idle
- 20% - Wi-Fi
- 6% - Display
- 2% - Angry Birds
- 2% - Maps

I have been on battery for 8h 50m, and the charge has gone from 100% to 64%.

Comment: What phone do you have? 2 days sounds like great battery life to me.

Comment: HTC Desire Z / T-Mobile G2

Comment: ~9 hours and only using 46% isn't bad at all. You can get more out of it by turning off GPS and wifi when not using it. A smart phone is a lot different then a feature phone. it takes a lot more to run the device. especially when they have ~1Ghz processors and such. even if you dont use the phone at all, the battery is going to drain because the system is running. its just like a laptop, if you dont shut if off completely, its going to use the battery even when your not using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out an app called [Watchdog](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zomut.watchdoglite).

It monitors your apps and alerts you to anything that is using your cpu excessively. It might help unless it something that's draining consistently at a low level.

I'd have to agree that it doesn't sound like you have a problem. Battery life seems good.

Juice Plotter is another battery monitor that you might be interested in and its companion app Juice defender might help squeeze extra life out of your phone as it can switch off your 3G off unless needed.

Comment: I wonder if these apps even work any more.  I had an app which would tell me in great detail exactly how much CPU each process used, but some time around Android 7 it stopped working because apps are suddenly prohibited from seeing this info.

Answer (score 3):

Everything drains the battery. The screen is usually a big drain on the battery. GPS will drain it, wifi, internet usage, phone calls, etc.

If you got 2 days out of one charge, then you got good usage out of it. My phone is almost always tethered to power whenever it is available. Desk at work, Desk at home, Car charger.

On my device (running CyanogenMod 7), I can go to Settings -> Application -> Battery Usage.

My screen shuts off after 15 seconds and it is 75% of the battery consumer.