# How can I prevent the battery in my Nexus S from draining overnight?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s, battery-life, charging

I have a Google Nexus S and for the past 2-3 days whenever I go to sleep the battery drains completely overnight. I mean when I go to bed the charge on my phone is plus 90% but for the past 2 days it's dead when I wake up. Thankfully I didn't miss work these two days otherwise my boss is gonna kill me.

I have Android 2.3.7

Any advice?

Comment: Plugging it in overnight seems like the trivial solution, but other than that, have you looked at [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-device)

Comment: Something is obviously running overnight. Check `Settings | About phone | Battery use` first thing in the morning to see what's draining it.

Comment: putting it to airplane mode overnight also is a good idea (except you need to get awoken by phone call, or must stay reachable). Some more details can be found at [Battery Sony Ericsson XPeria Mini Pro](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20510/battery-sony-ericsson-xperia-mini-pro/26950#26950).

Answer (score 1):

There are several things which can be done. Most obvious is to switch it off completely (*grin*), but that only as a side note. Also, switching it to Airplane mode falls close -- though, when used with a "timer" (via automation apps such as [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) or [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama)), it can be quite a useful thing to not only save some juice over night, but also care for some silence. Another obvious option is to connect it to some power source, which clearly prevents it from running out of juice. But these are just general rules.

In your special case, the problem is some app draining your battery over night. True, above mentioned solutions would take care that there's enough juice left -- but still that's a misbehaving app. So first thing I would do is, after it drained a little (but still enough juice is left, say 30% or more to be sure), go and check your battery stats. You will find them in your system settings, on most devices it is in *Settings → About Phone → Battery Use*. This should list the most heavy consumers, and your candidate should be on the very top.

Other useful sources on this topic (and here at Android Enthusiasts) include:

- [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/16575) (especially when you cannot find the "evil app" in the consumers list)
- [How can I tell what is really draining my battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10294/16575)
- [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/16575)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a custom ROM, check with its makers if there are any known causes for battery drain. Otherwise, (since there are no known issues with stock Android 2.3.7, the battery drain is caused by some app.

Turn off bluetooth and auto sync (leave wifi on), install [Watchdog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zomut.watchdoglite&hl=en) and charge the battery fully, then let your phone idle for a couple of hours. In that time, any apps that misbehave will be listed under the alerts tab of Watchdog. Check that and report here, maybe we can help.

If it does not list any app, try eliminating each of the common culprits for battery drain - social media (older versions of Facebook) and sync apps that constantly use connectivity options, free versions of apps that regularly pull in ads for display, location apps including Google's own reporting service. Uninstall or turn off whichever you can. If ads are an issue, and you are rooted, you can use Adblock.

Also, check for your battery health - if you've been a heavy user for over 2 years, it is likely that the battery has lost much of its original capacity, in which case a battery replacement would be necessary (I know because I have the same problem, and ordered a new battery yesterday). You can find OEM batteries for $30-40 - avoid cheap duplicates, you never know what they could do to your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Shut down your device overnight.

Or just plug it in before sleep.

Or buy a new one. After some time the battery want resist so much.

Oh.. of course... or buy a new battery.