# How can I monitor the device battery consumption?

Tags: battery, battery-life, resource-monitoring

I need information about which applications or hardware features discharge the battery. Built-in Android option for this doesn't fit because not all devices have it. Also it would be a great advantage if the solution would send statistics via email.

Comment: "Is there an app for X?" questions are off-topc per FAQ. That's why I rephrased your question.

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10294/how-can-i-tell-what-is-really-draining-my-battery

Comment: As far as I know all android devices have these statistics. If for some reason a device doesn't have them (old android or wierd manufacturer), then there is a good chance that the app can't get the information either Apps can only access what android provides, if android doesn't record it they can't get it either - except root apps but if you go as far as rooting than you might as well install a rom that has android statistics. It is possible that you just can't find the android statistics beacuse they are not in the ussual place, try searching the phone a bit more.

Comment: @Mihic unfortunately, some of the most important battery stats (wakelocks and some more) have been removed with Gingerbread ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at [SystemPanel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel)<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4478x.jpg)</sup> or [System Tuner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.pmw)<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbZup.jpg)</sup>. Both let you monitor your ressource consumption (not only battery), and (at least in their respective Pro versions) also offer to do so in background, collecting data for later evaluation. *System Tuner*<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbZup.jpg)</sup> also offers a bunch of nice widgets<sup>[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zabf.jpg)</sup> for your homescreen, if you need to watch things for a while.

[image: SystemPanel] [image: SystemTuner] [image: SystemTuner widgets]

**EDIT:**

After seeing Mihic's comment above, I noticed I missed another important point: While up to Froyo, "dialing" the magic number `*#*#4636#*#*` brought up a nice system menu (it still does *that* part) including many battery stats, the latter (battery stats) have been removed since Gingerbread. If your device is rooted, [BetterBatteryStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats) can bring those back -- and do a great deal to help you identifying battery hogs:

[image: BetterBatteryStats: Deepsleep] [image: BetterBatteryStats: Partial Wakelocks]

These two screenshots show you the most important information *BetterBatteryStats* provides: Which apps used the most battery power while the device tried to sleep<sup>[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zabf.jpg)</sup> -- and those who kept the device awake<sup>[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsPaX.jpg)</sup>, preventing DeepSleep and such "PowerSave Mode". Just helped me getting 20% more battery out of my device ;)