# Charging issues for Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, battery, battery-life

Just wanted to see if anyone knows what is going on with my Samsung Galaxy S2.

The problem is that when I fully charge the phone normally at night I have sometimes turned the phone off after it is charged but then in the morning it is close to completely drained.

Does anyone know what is going on with it?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, Caitlyn! Please check: [our battery-life tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery-life/info) for general hints, especially follow up to [How can I monitor the device battery consumption?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28570/16575) / [How can I tell what is really draining my battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/10294/16575) / [How can I prevent the battery in my Nexus S from draining overnight?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15658/16575) (that last one sounds familiar, right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Samsung galaxy S2 and was facing the same issue. And, If you are using Internet package to your phone and not logged off from any of the social network apps and also gtalk, facebook, gmail, e-mail etc the battery will be low even after you have completely charged your phone. And, of course if your phone is almost 3 year old you will face such problems.

I would suggest you to kindly disable the data network mode when not in use and this will increase the battery life.... :-)

I know this is not the permanent solution, but you can avoid your phone turned off when not in use.