# Battery-tracking app

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery-life

I have a Galaxy SIII on Jellybean that's about a year old. I've never had any battery issues with it. The last three days, it's been at 80% when I go to bed at night, and completely dead in the morning. Once it's charged (and it does appear to charge fully), it's fine all day, so there has to be some app that's hijacking it and running down the battery during the night. To the best of my recollection I have not installed anything new recently. I have GPS and wireless turned off by default.

Are there any apps out there that would produce a report of what apps are running at a given time (i.e. that I can look at after the fact; not something that shows me what's running now) and how much battery life they used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell what is really draining my battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10294/how-can-i-tell-what-is-really-draining-my-battery)

Comment: Not sure it's really a duplicate. That post indicates that the battery life is generally less than the user would expect, and that it appears to be draining over time. Mine is happening suddenly, and always during a very specific set of hours. I will check out the app posted in one of the answers, but am not sure it will help, as I assume that the phone has to be on to see the alerts, and my issue happens consistently in the middle of the night. That's why I'm asking for an app that does reporting.

Comment: Fair point. Take a look at [Wakelock detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector). It should show you if there is one (or more) apps keeping your phone awake overnight.

Comment: Will do. Hopefully it's something simple, and not that my phone is being remotely hacked or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wakelock detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector) should show you if there is one (or more) apps keeping your phone awake overnight.

You could also (if you're rooted) try [BetterBatteryStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats). It's a paid app but it can be found on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1179809) if you want to try it out (The thread was started by the author). I've included their message on why they make it available free on XDA below.

> BetterBatteryStats is available on the Android market for what I
>   believe is a fair price. If you like my work and want to support me
>   please fell free to show your gratitude by buying the app.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue a while ago. I was going through my Facebook and I saw and advertisement for a battery saving app called Battery Doctor. I have tried all kinds of battery saving apps but none of them really did the job quite as well as I was hoping, so I decided to give this one a chance. I downloaded it and was surprised at how well it works. It not only has a unique 3-step charging system but goes through your apps and tells you what apps are draining your battery and gives you the option to close them within the app. It keeps a graph of how many minutes you save when using the app. It is super helpful and i think you should try downloading this app to see if it fixes your problem. The best part about it is the app is free.[Here is the link to the app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ijinshan.kbatterydoctor_en)