# com.android.systemui rapid battery drain

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery-life

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 that is approximately six months old. My OS version is 4.4.2, and my provider is AT&T.

The battery in my S5 will usually last me 2-4 days without charging, depending on use, but two or three days ago the battery started dying very quickly despite minimal use. The battery will no longer even last 24 hours without use. I checked my phone's battery usage, and `com.android.systemui` seems to be causing the excess battery drain.

What's causing `com.android.systemui` to drain so much battery, and what can I do to fix it?

[image: Battery usage]
<sup>Battery usage (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Never seen SystemUI in that place. Usually I'd suggest to check for Wakelocks (see: [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/34969/16575)), or relate a question like [How can I tell what is really draining my battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/10294/16575) – as cases where "Android System" is listed on top, but the real issue being "something different" are not that rare. No idea what could stand behind SystemUI here; maybe the two links can shed a light nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't figured out what was causing the problem, but I did manage to fix it. I restarted my S5, and the process that was consuming all of the battery seems to have stopped. `com.android.systemui` is only responsible for 4% of the battery drain after restarting and recharging.

Answer (score 0):

com.android.systemui is the GUI for android every thing you do on your phone like typing or browsing the web will use this so it will drain your battery the most.

yo can try not using your phone for a day (put it on standby for 24 hours and see if it lasts) if it doesn't your battery maybe degraded and need replace.

Hoped this helped

Comment: `com.android.systemui` doesn't typically use as much power as Android System, Screen, or Android OS. Also, if this were a problem with the battery itself, it wouldn't have occurred suddenly and wouldn't be attributing all of the excess drain to one software process.