# New Galaxy S5 , Youtube is draining battery by 10 - 15%?

Tags: battery

I recently got my S5 and when I look in the battery settings I see that youtube is draining a lot of my battery. I couldnt greenify it and I don't know what to do. Sometimes it goes up to 22%

[image]

Comment: my biggest piece of advice is this: don't worry about what is draining your battery, especially the "percentage". Something is always going to be draining your battery, and something is always going to be the "main" consumer of the battery. These stats are based on since the last time you "fully charged" your phone too. They reset when you unplug from a full charge. I am going to guess you watch YouTube. YouTube is doing a lot of video rendering, which takes more "power" than listening to music without video.

Comment: related: [How can I tell what is really draining my battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10294/how-can-i-tell-what-is-really-draining-my-battery?rq=1)