# Does Greenify save battery usage?

Tags: battery-life

My phone drains a lot of battery during the day so I was wondering if the greenify app helps with the battery problem

Comment: A typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154) I'd say. Wasn't your real issue rather [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/476/16575) or [How can I tell what is really draining my battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/10294/16575) For some more, see our [battery-life tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery-life/info).

Answer (score 1):

They are right, it hibernates apps..if you are rooted with xposed it really does magic, but most modern apps are coded to restart persistently so a lot will restart after being hibernated because without root and xposed it can't hold the apps closed, it merely force stops them but that can still be effective if you only hibernate apps that don't restart until you open them. You'll have to just try and see which ones will behave, if you hibernate apps that restart and just keep closing then you will end up burning more battery. If you choose to root them you gotta lot of research and studying to do but it's well worth it but you gotta know what you're doing, good luck

Comment: Those who wants to know how those apps get restarted again, read about Broadcast receivers. About that, Dan Hulme has a very useful answer here: [What's the difference between a service and a broadcast receiver?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/46097)

Answer (score 0):

Technically YES. Basically what it does is hibernate selected apps. That means the apps you selected for greenification will not work service after inactivity like screen lock etc. They will start again as soon as you launch them again. So it should help battery problem!